# Удалить одинаковые элементы из двух векторов

Tags: c++

Подскажите как удалить одинаковые элементы у двух векторов( vector), а результат записать в третий вектор:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> vec1;
    vector<string> vec2;
    vector<string> vec3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (галочка слева от вопроса) ^__^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам самый простой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec1 = {"a", "abc", "bb"};
    std::vector<std::string> vec2 = {"abc", "ab", "bb"};
    std::vector<std::string> vec3;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto el = std::find(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1[i]);
        while (el != vec2.end())
        {
            vec1.erase(vec1.begin() + i);
            --i;
            vec2.erase(el);
            el = std::find(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1[i]);
        }
    }
    vec3 = vec1;
    vec3.insert(vec3.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < vec3.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec3[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В онлайн компиляторе: [тык](http://cpp.sh/7nidg) .

Comment: а с чего это самый простой вариант?...

Comment: Самый простой в смысле алгоритма, если не задумываться об оптимальности. А так да, наверное, можно придумать и более простой код, но врятли он будет принципиально проще... PS. Мой код содержал ошибку, выше я её исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень то ясно, с одного вектора хотите удалить эти элементы или с обеих, или просто записать в третий вектор... Я удалю с одного:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1{ "a", "abc", "bb", "dfy", "123" },
                       v2{ "abc", "ab", "123", "bb" }, res;
size_t k = 0;
auto first = v1.begin();
while (k < v1.size()) {
    auto It = std::find_first_of(first + k, v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    res.emplace_back(*It);
    k = It - first;
    v1.erase(It);
}
```